# Hide control inside repeater countrol if Container.index > 1 asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I want to run repeater control loop twice to show only two news items and i want to hide `<hr>` tag after first loop. I am not sure how i can use container.index method to hide `hr` tag .

```
<asp:repeater id="rptRepeater" runat="server">
    <separatortemplate>
                  <div id="one"><%=getTitle('title')%></div>
                  <div id="two"><%=getDescription('Desc')%></div>
          <hr id="hr" runat="server">
    </separatortemplate>
</asp:repeater>
```

I dont want to use jQuery for this i want to do it either from code behind or some repeater control property

Can i do something like <% if Container.index > 1 %> ... <% else %> ... in the same line where hr tag is included.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<asp:repeater id="rptRepeater" runat="server">
    <separatortemplate>
                  <div id="one"><%=getTitle('title')%></div>
                  <div id="two"><%=getDescription('Desc')%></div>
          <hr id="hr" runat="server" style='<%# (Container.index > 1)?"display:none;":""' %> >
    </separatortemplate>
</asp:repeater>
```